# In a .htaccess in Apache 2.4, the custom ErrorDocument 403 page not displayed on Require all denied

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to display a custom Error page for 403 status, but the default error page is displayed instead with the message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /access-denied

<If "req('Host') == 'mydomain.com'">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 24.24.24.24
</If>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Require ip 24.24.24.24
```

Since you have this directive it is generating `403` even for the error document `/access-denied`.

You can add another condition in `if` expression like this:

```sh
ErrorDocument 403 /access-denied

<If "req('Host') == 'mydomain.com' && %{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/access-denied#">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 24.24.24.24
</If>
```

Comment: i think there is a typo there should not be a " before %{REQUEST_URI

Comment: Yes that's right Martin it was indeed a typo. Thanks so much

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working. The ErrorDocument does not redirect to /access-denied, only display the content of the /access-denied page. 

So when facing the condition %REQUEST_URI is never access-denied (unless I explicity call the page (but wjy would a user request the /access-denied page))

Comment: `Q1. The ErrorDocument does not redirect to /access-denied` - That is expected behavior when we don't use `http://..` in front of `ErrorDocument 403`. If you want a full redirect then use `ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/access-denied` (do replace `example.com` with your own domain name). `Q2. Why would a user request the /access-denied page` - Use won't request that page but due to presence of `ErrorDocument 403` `REQUEST_URI`  will become `/access-denied` after rewrite or redirect. Hope it is more clear now.